# removeEventListener in a forEach loop works for 2nd element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I'm having an strange issue with Event Listeners, specifically removing them. In the below example I have a simple version, where I apply a mouseenter/mouseleave listener on desktop, and a click listener on mobile, however on resizing the browser, the event listener on the red box is removed correctly, but the event listener for the blue box is not.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {sliderAnim()})

function mobileBreakpoint() {
    const isDesktop = window.innerWidth
    if (isDesktop > 650) {
      return true
    }
    if (isDesktop <= 650) {
      return false
    }
  }

let animOverDesktop, animOutDesktop, animClickMobile, animClickSection
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".div")

function sliderAnim() {
  divs.forEach((div)=>{
    div.removeEventListener("mouseover", animOverDesktop);
    div.removeEventListener("mouseout", animOutDesktop);
    div.removeEventListener("click", animClickMobile);
  })

  
  if (mobileBreakpoint()) {
    divs.forEach((div, index) => {
      animOverDesktop = function () {
        gsap.to(div, {yPercent: 10, duration: 1})
      }

      animOutDesktop = function () {
        gsap.to(div, {yPercent: 0, duration: 1})
      }

      div.addEventListener("mouseover", animOverDesktop)
      div.addEventListener("mouseout", animOutDesktop)
    })
  }


  if (!mobileBreakpoint()) {
    divs.forEach((div, index) => {
      animClickMobile = function () {
         gsap.to(div, {xPercent: 10, duration: 1})
      }

      div.addEventListener("click", animClickMobile)
    })

  }
}
sliderAnim()
```

https://codepen.io/kolejain/pen/vYPKQrV

I've tried taking the removeEventListener out of the forEach function, and then it works perfectly fine. I think I'm referencing the functions correctly since this works for one of the boxes, but not the other. Is there something I'm missing here, I can't seem to find this issue anywhere else. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I can't answer why your current code doesn't work, but I did try an alternative using [AbortSignals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#signal) which did work better. See [my codepen](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/zYbBbyE)